# Control low battery mode from an iOS application

Tags: ios, battery, battery-saver

I would like switch on/off low power mode in an application. Is it possible to control battery mode from an iOS application.

Comment: Darn! Automatic disabling of low-power mode is my #1 complaint of iOS... I was hoping to write an app to always keep it low-power mode on.

Answer (score 3):

> **Apple has not exposed any public APIs to allow control of low power mode**.

but we can Detecting Low Power mode using the following code , the detail information provided in [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html)

**Objective C**

```
if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isLowPowerModeEnabled]) {
// Low Power Mode is enabled. Start reducing activity to conserve energy.
} else {
// Low Power Mode is not enabled.
}
```

**Swift**

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled {
            // Low Power Mode is enabled. Start reducing activity to conserve energy.
        } else {
            // Low Power Mode is not enabled.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i knew that we can get battery level information and low power mode is enabled or not. But looking for the public api to control the low power mode.

Comment: @MuruganandhamK - may be we can expect in future.